# Obtain importance of individual trees in a RandomForest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

### Question: Is there a way to extract the variable importance for each individual CART model from a `randomForest` object?

`rf_mod$forest` doesn't seem to have this information, and [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) don't mention it.

---

In R's `randomForest` package, the average variable importance for the entire forest of CART models is given by `importance(rf_mod)`.

```
library(randomForest)

df <- mtcars

set.seed(1)
rf_mod = randomForest(mpg ~ ., 
                      data = df, 
                      importance = TRUE, 
                      ntree = 200)

importance(rf_mod)

       %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  6.0927875     111.65028
disp 8.7730959     261.06991
hp   7.8329831     212.74916
drat 2.9529334      79.01387
wt   7.9015687     246.32633
qsec 0.7741212      26.30662
vs   1.6908975      31.95701
am   2.5298261      13.33669
gear 1.5512788      17.77610
carb 3.2346351      35.69909
```

We can also extract individual tree structure with `getTree`. Here's the first tree.

```
head(getTree(rf_mod, k = 1, labelVar = TRUE))
  left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1             2              3        wt        2.15     -3   18.91875
2             0              0      <NA>        0.00     -1   31.56667
3             4              5        wt        3.16     -3   17.61034
4             6              7      drat        3.66     -3   21.26667
5             8              9      carb        3.50     -3   15.96500
6             0              0      <NA>        0.00     -1   19.70000
```

One workaround is to grow many CARTs (i.e. - `ntree = 1`), get the variable importance of each tree, and average the resulting `%IncMSE`:

```
# number of trees to grow
nn <- 200

# function to run nn CART models 
run_rf <- function(rand_seed){
  set.seed(rand_seed)
  one_tr = randomForest(mpg ~ ., 
                        data = df, 
                        importance = TRUE, 
                        ntree = 1)
  return(one_tr)
}

# list to store output of each model
l <- vector("list", length = nn)
l <- lapply(1:nn, run_rf)
```

The extraction, averaging, and comparison step.

```
# extract importance of each CART model 
library(dplyr); library(purrr)
map(l, importance) %>% 
  map(as.data.frame) %>% 
  map( ~ { .$var = rownames(.); rownames(.) <- NULL; return(.) } ) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(`%IncMSE` = mean(`%IncMSE`)) %>% 
  arrange(-`%IncMSE`)

    # A tibble: 10 x 2
   var   `%IncMSE`
   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 wt        8.52 
 2 cyl       7.75 
 3 disp      7.74 
 4 hp        5.53 
 5 drat      1.65 
 6 carb      1.52 
 7 vs        0.938
 8 qsec      0.824
 9 gear      0.495
10 am        0.355

# compare to the RF model above
importance(rf_mod)

       %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  6.0927875     111.65028
disp 8.7730959     261.06991
hp   7.8329831     212.74916
drat 2.9529334      79.01387
wt   7.9015687     246.32633
qsec 0.7741212      26.30662
vs   1.6908975      31.95701
am   2.5298261      13.33669
gear 1.5512788      17.77610
carb 3.2346351      35.69909
```

---

I'd like to be able to extract the variable importance of each tree **directly from a `randomForest` object**, **without** this roundabout method that involves completely re-running the RF in order to facilitate reproducible [cumulative variable importance plots like this one](https://twitter.com/RichPauloo/status/1124470765095538688), and the one below shown for `mtcars`. [Minimal example here](https://gist.github.com/richpauloo/8742761e131bd6a0486a40df2b9d1f01).

I'm aware that a single tree's variable importance is not statistically meaningful, and it's not my intention to interpret trees in isolation. I want them for the purpose of visualization and communicating that as trees increase in a forest, the variable importance measures jump around before stabilizing.

[image]

Comment: You can check if `tree` or `rpart` will accept trees built by `randomForest` and, if so, use the variable importance functions from these packages.

Comment: Hello, how did you realize the interactive plot above please ? Thank you !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When training a `randomForest` model, the importance scores are computed for the entire forest and stored directly inside the object. Tree-specific scores are not kept and so cannot be directly retrieved from a `randomForest` object.

Unfortunately, you are correct about having to incrementally construct a forest. The good news is that a `randomForest` object is self-contained, and you don't need to implement your own `run_rf`. Instead, you can use `stats::update` to re-fit the random forest model with a single tree and `randomForest::grow` to add additional trees one at a time:

```
## Starting with a random forest having a single tree,
##   grow it 9 times, one tree at a time
rfs <- purrr::accumulate( .init = update(rf_mod, ntree=1),
                          rep(1,9), randomForest::grow )

## Retrieve the importance scores from each random forest
imp <- purrr::map( rfs, ~importance(.x)[,"%IncMSE"] )

## Combine all results into a single data frame
dplyr::bind_rows( !!!imp )
# # A tibble: 10 x 10
#      cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt   qsec    vs     am    gear  carb
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 0      18.8  8.63 1.05   0     1.17  0     0       0      0.194
#  2 0      10.0 46.4  0.561  0    -0.299 0     0       0.543  2.05 
#  3 0      22.4 31.2  0.955  0    -0.199 0     0       0.362  5.1
#  4 1.55   24.1 23.4  0.717  0    -0.150 0     0       0.272  5.28
#  5 1.24   22.8 23.6  0.573  0    -0.178 0     0      -0.0259 4.98
#  6 1.03   26.2 22.3  0.478  1.25  0.775 0     0      -0.0216 4.1
#  7 0.887  22.5 22.5  0.406  1.79 -0.101 0     0      -0.0185 3.56
#  8 0.776  19.7 21.3  0.944  1.70  0.105 0     0.0225 -0.0162 3.11
#  9 0.690  18.4 19.1  0.839  1.51  1.24  1.01  0.02   -0.0144 2.77
# 10 0.621  18.4 21.2  0.937  1.32  1.11  0.910 0.0725 -0.114  2.49
```

The data frame shows how feature importance changes with each additional tree. This is the right panel of your plot example. The trees themselves (for the left panel) can be retrieved from the final forest, which is given by `dplyr::last( rfs )`.

Comment: Elegant solution +1

Comment: I've learned along the way that this question as it stands is un-anwserable without a re-write of `randomForest`. However, this solution is the most creative and promising. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer: This is not really an answer, but too long to post as a comment. Will remove if deemed not appropriate.**

While I (think I) understand your question, to be honest I am unsure whether your question makes sense from a statistics/ML point-of-view. The following is based on my obviously limited understanding of RF and CART. Perhaps my comment-post will lead to some insights.

Let's start with some general random forest (RF) theory on variable importance from [Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman, *The Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), p. 593 (bold-face mine):

> At each split in each tree, the improvement in the split-criterion is the
>   importance measure attributed to the splitting variable, and **is accumulated
>   over all the trees in the forest separately for each variable**. [...]
>   Random forests also use the oob samples to construct a different variable-importance measure, apparently to measure the prediction strength of each variable.

So the variable importance measure in RF is *defined* as a measure **accumulated over all trees**.

---

In traditional single classification trees (CARTs), variable importance is characterised through the Gini index that measures node impurity (see e.g. [How to measure/rank “variable importance” when using CART? (specifically using {rpart} from R)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/how-to-measure-rank-variable-importance-when-using-cart-specifically-using) and [Carolin Strobl's PhD thesis](http://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/8904/1/Strobl_Carolin.pdf))

More complex measures to characterise variable importance in CART-like models exist; for example in [`rpart`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf):

> An overall measure of variable importance is the sum of the goodness of split
>   measures for each split for which it was the primary variable, plus goodness * (adjusted
>   agreement) for all splits in which it was a surrogate. In the printout these are scaled to sum
>   to 100 and the rounded values are shown, omitting any variable whose proportion is less
>   than 1%.

---

So the bottom line here is the following: At the very least it won't be easy (and in the worst case it won't make sense) to compare variable measures from single classifaction trees with variable importance measures applied to ensemble-based methods like RF.

Which leads me to ask: *Why* do you want to extract variable importance measures for individual trees from an RF model? Even if you came up with a method to calculate variable importances from individual trees, I believe they wouldn't be very meaningful, and they wouldn't have to "converge" to the ensemble-accumulated values.

Comment: Hi @Maurits, thanks for your comment and interest in this. I'm familiar with the fact that the variable importance of a RF only makes sense as an aggregate measure, as any one tree will be biased toward the subset of predictors chosen for the splits. My motivation is to create **interpretable** visualizations, showing that as the number of trees increases in a forest, the variable importance measures jump around, and then stabilize. An example of this is shown above in my edited post, and [available as a gist here](https://gist.github.com/richpauloo/8742761e131bd6a0486a40df2b9d1f01).

Comment: Within `randomForest` it seems that the importance per tree is calculated in the underlying C code. I'm not sure about `ranger` or other implementations. The nice thing about `randomForest` is the `getTree` function which returns the tree structure of individual trees in the forest. This may be more work than I have time for, which is okay, I just wanted to toss this out to the denizens of SO in case it was actually easy.

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify it by

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map(seq_len(nn),  ~ 
          run_rf(.x) %>% 
          importance) %>%
       reduce(`+`) %>% 
       magrittr::divide_by(nn)
```

Comment: This is an obvious improvement in the clarity of the code. Thanks! However, I'd like to make a package where people supply a `randomForest` object. This approach still requires re-running the model from scratch... I'm not sure `randomForest` supports what I'm asking for.

Comment: are u getting the model object with `load/save` etc.  If it is a reuse purpose after building the model, would store the model with `save`, then at the time of scoring, `load`.  In case, you are storing it on hdfs, you can do this with `webHDFS` via pickling/unpickling.  I have done these both easily without much issues

Comment: I'm imagining that people supply a `randomForest` object, and the package functions take that object and calculate the cumulative `%IncMSE` as a function of `ntree`. Not sure if that answers your question...

Comment: @RichPauloo  I understand your question.  model objects stored as a pickled/serialized object is retreived via unpickling/unserialized and then pass the function to extract the values

Comment: Okay, I'm learning some things! Thans @akrun. In this case, yes, I am imagining that the users will be able to save a model, load it later, and run it through the function. I'm not sure how it relates to obtaining individual `%IncMSE` scores from trees within a `randomForest` though. But I think you see something I don't.

Comment: @RichPauloo  If you check the code, before the `reduce` step, it is a `list` of importance values, which I sum it together and divide.  So, if you stop at that point, it would be a list

Comment: hmmm I think my question is not clear enough. I'm able to obtain the list (one tree per element). In the example, I want to get this same result from the `rf_mod` (see first code block).

Comment: @RichPauloo  If you look at the `ntree`, it is 200 in the first block, while in the one going into function, it is `ntree = 1`

Comment: That's exactly correct, and motivates this question! In the third code block, I write the `run_rf` function to grow RFs of `ntree = 1` because then I can use `importance` on each tree. The heart of my question is: can I obtain these "tree-by-tree" scores from `rf_mod`, the RF of `ntree = 200` in code block 1, without needing to run code block 3 in the first place?

Comment: First of all, the `run_rf` is a function and not a model object.  So, it is not reproducible